# Why the word "projective" for $PGL_n(\mathbb{F})$?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, projective-geometry

I wrote the title for this question exactly as I had it exactly in my mind. Let me denote by $G=GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ for simplicity; I was working throughout the previous years many times with the quotient $G/Z(G)$ (i.e. the group of inner automoprhisms of $G$) which is known as the "projective linear group" and it is denoted explicitly as $PGL_n(\mathbb{F})$. Now my question as it mentioned in the title is why the name of that group contains the word "projective". Apparently there is a correlation with projective geometry, whilst whether $n=2$ we have the so-called Möbius Transformation group. At the Wiki article the situation (at least in my eyes) isn't that clear. So can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Related :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731833/natural-way-of-looking-at-projective-transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general linear group $GL_n(k)$ is the group of automorphisms (in a suitable sense) of the $n$-space $k^n$. Similarly, the projective linear group $PGL_n(k)$ is the group of automorphisms (in a suitable sense<sup>*</sup>) of the projective $n$-space $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$.

In projective geometry, two nonzero points are identified if they are on a same line going through the origin. (The relation with [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry) is well explained at Wikipedia.) So it's natural to think that a transformation that takes any line to itself (i.e. all vectors are eigenvectors) acts "trivially" on the projective space. This explains why we must at least quotient out by the scalar multiple of the identity.

It's then an exercise to show that if a linear map is such that all vectors are eigenvectors, then the linear map is a scalar multiple of the identity. So we don't need to quotient out by anything else.

---

<sup>*</sup> The group $PGL_n(k)$ is the set of invertible elements of the monoid of functions $\mathbb{P}^n(k) \to \mathbb{P}^n(k)$ which come from linear maps $k^{n+1} \to k^{n+1}$ under the identification $\mathbb{P}^n(k) = (k^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}) / \sim$.

Comment: Thank you Najib, i think you were clear! You helped me!

Comment: I guess that Najib means that by its construction, a projective space comes up by "moding out" the equivalence relation given by this sentence. So I can't see why are you saying that it is vague?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi one more question, by "a suitable sense" I guess that you mean, categorically that automorphisms in that case are bijections of $\mathbb{P}(V)$  as a set?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris $GL_n(k)$ are automorphisms of the vector space $k^n$, but $PGL_n(k)$ are the automorphisms of $P(k^n)$ among the endomorphisms of $P(k^n)$ that come from linear maps $k^{n+1} \to k^{n+1}$. That is, $PGL_n(k)$ is the group of invertible elements of the monoid $\{ f : P(k^n) \to P(k^n) \mid \exists g \in \operatorname{Lin}(k^{n+1}, k^{n+1}) \text{ s.t. } f = [g] \}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thank you a lot for your comments they are really useful. I understand completely the above that you have written, however there is something that I don't get for some reason. This monoid that yields $PGL_n(\mathbb{F)}$ as group of invertible elements, consists of set-theoritic maps, right? We don't assume any additional (algebraic structure) for $\mathbb{P}(k^n)$ for that right?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I'm not an expert on this, but my guess is that the automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ seen as an algebraic variety would exactly be $PGL_n(k)$. (You could ask a new question about this, because I definitely don't know enough to give an actual answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The *projective plane* over $\mathbb F$ arises from $\mathbb F^3$ by excluding the origin and then identifying vectors that are multiples of each other.

Similarly, $PGL_n(\mathbb F)$ arises from the set of $n\times n$ matrices by excluding the singular matrices and then identifying matrices that are multiples of each other (because the center of the general linear group consists of exactly the scalar multiples of $I$).